# Sync PouchDB with CouchDB server

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I follow the guide getting started from [getting started](http://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html)

For enable CORS the guide proposes this command:

```
    $ curl -X PUT $HOST/_config/httpd/enable_cors -d '"true"'
    $ curl -X PUT $HOST/_config/cors/origins -d '"*"'
    $ curl -X PUT $HOST/_config/cors/credentials -d '"true"'
    $ curl -X PUT $HOST/_config/cors/methods -d '"GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE"'
    $ curl -X PUT $HOST/_config/cors/headers -d \
      '"accept, authorization, content-type, origin"
```

But I read in the file default.ini, that I can’t set origins: * and credentials = true at the same time. In effect if I follow the above command the synchronization work well.

Why therefore default.ini say that isn't possible set origins: * and credentials = true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the CORS spec says so:

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-requests 6.1.3

Have you tried replicating using CORS from two different hosts using credentials with the * setting? If that works that is a bug in CouchDB and we should fix it. Note that CouchDB will allow you to configure things as you describe, but you shouldn’t be able to replicate with credentials across hosts then.

Comment: I tried to sync my db with a friend using this setting and synchronization work well.